# How to use subfigure to make the following table of figures

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

|Fig A| FigC|

|Fig B|   - |

FigC should span the entire column. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SE! You need to provide more data about your document and also what you try so far.  The best would be Minimal Working Example (MWE), small complete document, which can be compiled.

Comment: If Fig C spans the whole column, where is Fig A meant to go? It looks as if it goes on the left, but then Fig C can't take the whole column.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean something like the below code. I've used the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment for subfigures, but the same principle will apply for other packages. Put the first two subfigures in a `minipage` environment, and the third one just after the `minipage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\caption{The first subfigure}
\label{fig:partI}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\caption{The second subfigure}
\label{fig:partII}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=7cm]{example-image}
\caption{The third subfigure}
\label{fig:partIII}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{The whole shebang.}
\label{fig:thewholething}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```